# Verbal Job Offer and Training Date But No Email

Tags: job-offer, email

I went to an interview, and received a job offer later that day over the phone. She told me the amount I'd be paid, the department I'd be in and the day to come in for training. I was told I would receive an email with all of the required information, but I did not receive it.  That was about 2 weeks ago.

Since then I've called twice, only to be told I would receive an email in a couple of days, but as of yet I haven't received anything.  The woman on the phone knows that I am an internal transfer (I have worked for the company as a seasonal employee), so perhaps I'm already in the system.  I'm getting worried because I rejected other interviews because this was the place I really wanted to work.

Was I really officially hired?  Since I have been allocated a training date, I have the impression that I have.

Comment: Related: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to not accept the 'I'll send you an email in a couple of days' and say you've heard that a lot of times in a polite way.

Try to ask something like that:

'Hey, with ***. A few weeks ago you sent me a mail with a job offer. I've been told I would get an email with all required details, and I still haven't. Every time I call I get told I would get the email in a couple of days but I never received the email.'

Just be polite and explain you have been told the same thing over and over again. If nothing happens, I think you'd better be off searching for something different. Because telling somebody over and over again you'll send a mail but you will never do is not very professional in my opinion.